# How does carcinoma enter into blood or lymphatic vessels？

Tags: cell-biology, cancer, cell-signaling

When carcinoma begins to metastasize, it enters into blood vessel or lymphatic vessel to migrate to the site of metastasis. In that case, although I think breaking down the basement membrane is necessary for epithelium such as carcinoma to enter into them, I can't find out the reports. 
Are the basement membrane actually broken down in the first step of metastasis？What are the molecular mechanisms in which carcinoma enters into blood or lymphatic vessels？

Comment: You can read about [epithelial to mesenchymal transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithelial%E2%80%93mesenchymal_transition). It is one of the processes that usually precedes metastasis of carcinomas.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I have already known that the EMT system is one of ways of metastasis. However what i want to know is whether carcinoma actually breaks down the basement membrane when it stats to metastasize. Do you know some reports showing histochemically the broken down basement membrane？

Comment: @ironKUMA The linked Wikipedia article has many citations to the primary literature, I would suggest starting there. You should also perform some appropriately-worded Google Scholar and PubMed searches for more information.